# Split a string on delimiter with SQL in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I've got a table of 8 million+ records in SFMC with one column called "AllData" and records that look like this:

```
D||John Smith|EML|johnsmith@gmail.com|Y|2014/10/22 10:15:08.000000|
```

I'm not looking to import a file, this data already exists as is, and cannot be cleaned externally unfortunately.

I've tried this method:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(a.alldata, 1, isnull(p1-1, len(a.alldata))) detailrecordid,
       SUBSTRING(a.alldata, p1+1, ISNULL(p2, LEN(a.alldata)+1)-p1-1) cid,
       SUBSTRING(a.alldata, p2+1, ISNULL(p3, LEN(a.alldata)+1)-p2-1) name,
       SUBSTRING(a.alldata, p3+1, ISNULL(p4, LEN(a.alldata)+1)-p3-1) contacttypecd,
       SUBSTRING(a.alldata, p4+1, ISNULL(p5, LEN(a.alldata)+1)-p4-1) contactdata,
       SUBSTRING(a.alldata, p5+1, ISNULL(p6, LEN(a.alldata)+1)-p5-1) consentstatus,
       SUBSTRING(a.alldata, p6+1, ISNULL(p7, LEN(a.alldata)+1)-p6-1) collectts,
       SUBSTRING(a.alldata, p7+1, ISNULL(p8, LEN(a.alldata)+1)-p7-1) dateconsentupdated
FROM test_consent_9f_space a CROSS apply
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata), 0)) b(p1) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p1+1), 0)) c(p2) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p2+1), 0)) d(p3) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p3+1), 0)) e(p4) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p4+1), 0)) f(p5) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p5+1), 0)) g(p6) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p6+1), 0)) h(p7) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p7+1), 0)) i(p8)
```

But the performance is extremely slow - any other ideas on how to efficiently comb through 8 million rows?

I'm thinking of potentially just focusing on email address if it had to really come down to it:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(a.alldata, p4+1, ISNULL(p5, LEN(a.alldata)+1)-p4-1) contactdata
FROM test_consent_9f_space a CROSS apply
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata), 0)) b(p1) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p1+1), 0)) c(p2) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p2+1), 0)) d(p3) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p3+1), 0)) e(p4) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p4+1), 0)) f(p5) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p5+1), 0)) g(p6) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p6+1), 0)) h(p7) CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT nullif(charindex('|', a.alldata, p7+1), 0)) i(p8)
```

Comment: I'd push back. SFMC isn't the place for ETL operations like this.  Tell them that the fine folks on SFSE say so.

Comment: I agree SFMC is no place for ETL, and am pretty adamant about that, unfortunately I inherited work that was in the queue for a year now that was promised in SFMC. I've decided to go with just extracting one piece of data which performed in under 30 minutes and highlight that SFMC  shouldn't be used in this scenario due to risk of timing out. I borrowed this query concept from your blog, so thanks for that!

Comment: Can't add a new answer for some reason, and while I agree with @AdamSpriggs, sometimes you have to work with what you have. So here's something you can try: EXPORT your single-column DE to a CSV file on your SFTP, as-is. Then move that file to your SFTP Import folder, and Import it into a new DE, using the pipe (|) as your delimiter. Might get you there. Good luck!